# Place WPF Popup Along Bottom of Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, popup

I have a `Popup` that consists of a grid of labels. The popup sits inside a Canvas like this.

```
   <Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas">
        <Popup x:Name="mainPopup" 
               IsOpen="True"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=mainCanvas}"
               PopupAnimation="Fade"
               AllowsTransparency="True"
               Placement="Center">
```

Wrapping inside the canvas (or similar control) is the only way I've found to allow the popup's contents to be transparent.

Anyway, all of this works fine and I see my grid of labels across the center of the screen. What I'd really want though is to display the grid of labels across the *bottom* of the screen. However when I change `Placement="Center"` to `Placement="Bottom"`, I don't see the popup at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750577(v=vs.85).aspx)? It is a pretty good explanation about how popup placement works.

I created a test WPF project in Blend and pasted your exact code, then changed Placement to Bottom. I *did* see the content I added to the popup (a TextBlock with some junk text), but it was hard to see, since it is positioned *below* mainCanvas (as expected).

So... there must be some other problem aside from the code you showed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had googled around for an MSDN article on Popup Placement but didn't find this.